# Parsing Data in powershell, with the format of Label:Data

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

I am doing a `Invoke-Webrequest` in powershell to an url that does not contain any HTML, just text. I am needing to pick out a specific part of this data that is in the format of `Label:Data`. Each piece of data is one it's own separate line. I'm looking for some ideas on how to accomplish this. Here is a sample of the `$Response.Content`data below. I am looking to isolate the `speed-over-ground:0.0`

```
rate-of-turn:0.0
course-over-ground:293.0
speed-over-ground:0.0
heading-true:243.0
hdop:1.0
active-waypoint-name:
bearing-to-waypoint:
distance-to-waypoint:
cross-track-error:0
cross-track-error-limit:
cross-track-error-scale:0
lateral-speed-bow:0.09
lateral-speed-stern:-0.05
longitudinal-speed:-0.05
```

Comment: Are you just wanting the value on the right side of speed-over-ground? And  is this in multiple places in the content you are searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a single string, rather than an array of lines. So, split it into lines:

```
$Response.Content -split "`r?`n"
```

Find the one which says `speed-over-ground`

```
$line = $Response.Content -split "`r?`n" | Where-Object { $_ -match 'speed-over-ground' }
```

Split the text from the number, using the `:` separator, and take the second item, converted from text to a number if appropriate:

```
[decimal]$speedOverGround = $line.Split(':')[1]
```

Although, I might try to turn all of them into an object in a bulk transform. Complexity varies with the exact possible inputs, but this tries to convert numbers to numbers and leave empty ones as nulls:

```
$data = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject 
$Response.Content -split "`r?`n" -replace ':\s*$', ':$null' |
    ForEach-Object {

        $name, $value = $_.Split(':').Trim()
        $decimalValue = 0
        if ([decimal]::TryParse($value, [ref]$decimalValue))
        {
            $value = $decimalValue
        }


        $data | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $value

    }

# Then you can do:
$data.'speed-over-ground'
```